# Java : Operators and Typecasting

Tags: java, operators, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, typecast-operator

```
long value = 0x88888888 ;
int i = (int) (value & 0xff);
```

How does the above evaluation of expression take place? Is it

```
int i = (int)value & (int)0xff ;
```

or does the bitwise and operation gets evaluated first? I am getting confused :-|

Comment: Anything within `()` is evaluated before anything outside is applied.  The standard rule is that the shorter operand is extended to match the longer.

Comment: But does it matter? Either way `i = 0x88`

Comment: That's what was my understanding. But I got a little confused. Thanks!

Comment: Yes it doesn't matter if the value is <= 0xffffffff . But if it becomes more than that, the result will be impacted, isn't it?

Comment: Well, in general yes, but not if you AND it with 255

Comment: @sk89 I don't think it ever makes a difference with bitwise operators (`&`, `|`, `^`, `~`), because the contents of the higher-order bits never affect what happens to the lower-order bits or vice versa.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thank you for clearing that up for me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First the bitwise operation is evaluated as an operation on longs (the parenthesis guarantee it). Then the result is cast to int.

Comment: Thank you! Was getting confused!

Answer (score 5):

Lets take a look at the [bytecode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode):

```
 public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
    0: ldc2_w        #35                 // long -2004318072l
    3: lstore_1
    4: lload_1
    5: ldc2_w        #37                 // long 255l
    8: land
    9: l2i
   10: istore_3
   11: return
}
```

as you can see the hexadecimal `0xff` is first converted to long and then use the `bitwise and` to the **value** by masking it with the `0xff`  after it is then converted to `int`

- `lload_1` load a long value from a local variable 1
- `ldc2_w` push a constant #index from a constant pool (double or long) onto the stack
- `land` bitwise and of two longs
- `l2i` convert a long to a int

Answer (score 0):

First `(value & 0xff);` will be solved. i.e `value(bitwise and)0xff.` 
then the resultant will be converted to int value using type casting `int i = (int) (value & 0xff);`